# Django: can't combine Class-based detail and form views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm new to Django, was starting on usual function-type views, but I'm asked to do this only on class-based views.
So there's a problem. I need to make a view, that does next things:
- shows a selected question
- shows all answers to that question
- contains a form, that allows to add a new answer to this question.

My models.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Question(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='questions')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    number_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    number_answers = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Answer(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='answers')
    question = models.ForeignKey("Question", related_name="answers")
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from apps.questions.models import Question, Answer

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['title', 'text']

class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['text']
```

code from views.py, I took some similar example from django docs , but it doesn't work...

```
class QuestionDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'questions/detail.html'
    model = Question

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuestionDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = AnswerForm()
        return context

class AnswerView(FormView, SingleObjectMixin):
    template_name = 'questions/detail.html'
    form_class = AnswerForm
    model = Answer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super(AnswerView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

class QuestionDisplay(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = QuestionDetail.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = AnswerView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.QuestionDisplay.as_view(), name='detail'),
)
```

This code shows the details of the selected question and related answers. But when I enter some new answer in a form and click submit, it just returns an error "Page not found" without any traceback or something and with a link to a same URL, where question details and answer form are stored.

---

Poblem solved:

```
class QuestionDetail(DetailView, ModelFormMixin, ProcessFormView):
    template_name = 'questions/detail.html'
    model = Question
    form_class = AnswerForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('questions:detail', kwargs={'pk':self.get_object().id})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuestionDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.form_class
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = Answer(author=request.user, question=self.get_object())
        return super(QuestionDetail, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.QuestionDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

in urls.py

Comment: What doesn't work? What part are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: Well, this code shows the details of the selected question and related answers. But when I enter some new answer in a form and click submit, it just returns an error "Page not found" with a link to a same URL, where question details and answer form are stored.

Comment: You need [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets), along with a `CreateView` and then load the form with the question selected; which will populate the sub-forms with the existing answers and add an aditional (empty) form for the new answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are two alternative approaches to your solution which avoid overriding the `post` method:

One is to use a `DetailView` and add a form in the context. In the template, though, you need to actually specify the `action` attribute for the form tag, pointing to a separate `FormView` using the same form. This one is similar to your solution, but with a separate `FormView` which can be then used separately if necessary.

The other is using a `FormView` which will also include the `Question` object, based on a URL parameter. You can use that object to display its contents, populate your form's fields and so on.